# How to link one .exe to another .exe in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog, linker

I have two `.exe`s. They need to use each other's functions at run times. One is dilogue based application `.exe` and other one is main application `.exe`. Now main application need to use dialog based applications function. But while compiling it could bot able to locate the existance of `called function` because unavailability of `dialog based applications .lib`. Because if i make dialog based application to `.lib`, then the program will fail at run time. So, I need to make call one `.exe` to other `.exe`.
When I am trying call,

```
  TestClass tc;/* Call dialog based application exe functions*/
   tc.MyTest();
```

It is throwing errors like

```
1>CallExe.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TestClass::~TestClass(void)" (??1TestClass@@QAE@XZ)
1>CallExe.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall TestClass::MyTest(void)" (?MyTest@TestClass@@QAEXXZ)
1>CallExe.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TestClass::TestClass(void)" (??0TestClass@@QAE@XZ)
```

`Main application.cpp`

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   STARTUPINFO si;     
   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  TestClass tc;/* Call dialog based application exe functions*/
   tc.MyTest();

   // set the size of the structures
   ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
   si.cb = sizeof(si);
   ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
   LPCTSTR szCmdline = (LPCTSTR)(TEXT("Dialog.exe"));

  // start the program up
  if(!CreateProcess(TEXT("D:\\Rasmi's\\Personal\\Visual Studio\\Dialog\\Debug\\Dialog.exe"),   // the path
    argv[1],        // Command line

        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
      {cout << "Unable to create\n";}
        // Close process and thread handles. 
        CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
        CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

        return 0;
    }
```

In `Dialog.exe`

```
TestClass::TestClass(void)
{
}


TestClass::~TestClass(void)
{
}
void TestClass::MyTest()
{
    cout << "This is my Test Class \n";
}
```

Comment: why not put the dialog used in both applications in a separate library you reference from both exes?

Comment: This cannot work, a DLL is required.  Which will probably "fail at run time" as well if you don't address the core problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned, you have a fundamental design problem.  You haven't said why you need two executables, but if you truly do have a need for two separate applications to interact with each other, then you will need to use some form of [interprocess communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If your two applications need only to share common code to display dialog forms, but do not need interact with each other, then you can create a DLL project to contain the shared code.  Both of your applications will then link with this DLL.  See [MFC Extension DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20ytt2wa.aspx) for examples.

Answer (score 3):

you can use following code for launching your exe .

```
char exePath[200];
STARTUPINFO         si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
si.dwFlags     = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE; //SW_SHOWDEFAULT;        //Hide the DOS or Console Window
si.hStdInput;
cstring sPrjPath="D:\\Rasmi's\\Personal\\Visual Studio\\Dialog\\Debug";
    sprintf(exePath,"Dialog.exe %s\", sPrjPath);


::SetCurrentDirectory(sPrjPath);

if( !CreateProcess( NULL, // No module name (use command line).
    exePath,      // Command line.
    NULL,                 // Process handle not inheritable.
    NULL,                 // Thread handle not inheritable.
    FALSE,                // Set handle inheritance to FALSE.
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,// No creation flags.
    NULL,                 // Use parent's environment block.
    NULL,                 // Use parent's starting directory.
    &si,                  // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
    &pi )                 // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
    )
{
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    // Close process and thread handles.
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    return;
}
WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
// Close process and thread handles.
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm, you can't do like that.
if you want to have a interaction between to apps like calling procedures and functions you need to use something like xml-rpc, if i understood you correctly

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to send a WM_USER message using SendMessage() to the dialog-based application and catch it in the message loop (use FindWindow() to get the handle). If you have any arguments to pass, consider using WM_COPYDATA.